# heap corruption when free() struct pointer after memcpy

Tags: c++, c, memcpy, heap-corruption

I'm writing a generic sorting function with C using Visual Studio 2019.

I made an generic insertion sort function with prototype:

```cpp
void insertion_sort(void* const arr, size_t left, size_t right, size_t width, _Cmpfun cmp)
```

where `_Cmpfunc` is typedef as

```cpp
typedef int (*_Cmpfun) (const void*, const void*);
```

To test this function working I made an structure ELEMENT for the test like this.

```cpp
typedef struct {
    unsigned int score;
    float data[3];
    char comments[16];
} ELEMENT;
```

In order to save a data, I dynamically allocated memory like this.

```cpp
    char* top_ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(width));
```

Whenever I try to `free()` `top_ptr` after

```cpp
memcpy(top_ptr, some_valid_pointer, width)
```

where some_valid_pointer is not NULL pointer and width is parameter of insertion_sort

, Visual Studio pops Heap corruption error.

This happens only after `memcpy` function is called.

If I do like this :

```cpp
char* top_ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(width));
free(top_ptr);
```

it works fine.

I've search what is Heap corruption error in the web and found it occurs when `memcpy` function overwrites the invalid memory of structure variable.

I call function `insertion_sort` with `width = sizeof(ELEMENT)` in `main` so padding of struct variable is considered.

I have no idea what is the problem. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: We can’t say without seeing the actual code. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Also note that C and C++ are different languages, pick one.

Comment: `size_t width` is the bytes of a single element of `arr`. For example the pointer of the next element of `arr[0]`  would be `arr + width`. How can the underlying structure is larger than width? (the function is called with `width = sizeof(ELEMENT)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
width = sizeof(ELEMENT)
```

`sizeof(ELEMENT)`, using back-of-the-envelope calculations, should be be in the neighborhood of about 30 bytes. That's how big your `ELEMENT` is.

```
char* top_ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(width));
```

Since `width` is a `size_t`, `sizeof(size_t)` will be either 4 or 8, depending upon whether you're compiling 32 or 64 bit code.

So, this will allocate 4 or 8 bytes. Far short of 30 bytes being `memcpy`ed.

That's your heap corruption, right here.

Comment: Oh I should have call `malloc(width)`. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating memory of size `sizeof(width)`:

```
char* top_ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(width));
```

but copying memory of size `width`:

```
memcpy(top_ptr, some_valid_pointer, width)
```

Most likely `sizeof(width) < width`, hence the heap corruption.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made a silly mistake...